# Move the navigation to the left

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I  and trying to move the navigation menu (which is a list) to the left side  below the slogan and logo.I have tried various things but somehow the problem is not being solved. Despite my efforts the navigation bar seems to float besides the logo but not under it as it should.
Here is the link
http://contestlancer.com/greenFields/

Any help would be appreciated
Regards,
Ahmar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This moved the menu under the slogan for me:

```
ul#top-menu {
    float: none;
}
```

Comment: Because float:left is forcing #top-menu directly next to the edge of #slogan.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to move it to the left of div?

Comment: You said you wanted #top-menu under #slogan, which is what happens now. float:left effectively puts #top-menu on the right of #slogan.

Comment: doesn't make sense to me however thanks a lot Eric for helping .

Comment: My pleasure. The best way to see what I mean is use Firefox's 3D view to see the difference between the two float values being applied to #top-menu. If my answer helped, please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the float from `ul#top-menu` and then adjust the left margin on the slogan to

```
p#slogan {
margin-left:-185px;
}
```